# EF6 Many-To-Many Join-Tables Half or Fully Broken

Tags: sql, .net-core, entity-framework-6, many-to-many, console-application

I'm working on a database exercise project, effectively "porting" a board game to a command line project.

I have several tables that effectively serve to join tables that are related via Many-to-Many relationships. For example, a single boardSpace may exist upon several mapPanels, and a single mapPanel has several dozen boardSpaces. I have a BoardSpace table, a MapPanel table, and a BoardSpaceMapPanel table, the rows of which are only ever built once, and are just pulled for each game, depending on which pieces of the map board are being used.

```
    public class BoardSpaceMapPanel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public BoardSpace BoardSpace { get; set; }
        public MapPanel MapPanel { get; set; }
        public BoardSpaceMapPanel()
        {

        }
        public BoardSpaceMapPanel(BoardSpace boardSpace, MapPanel mapPanel)
        {
            BoardSpace = boardSpace;
            MapPanel = mapPanel;
        }
    }

    public class BoardSpace
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public enum CitySiteType
        {
            None,
            Normal,
            Flood
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public CitySiteType CitySite { get; set; }
        public bool FloodPlane { get; set; }
        public int MaxPop { get; set; }
        public Volcano Volcano { get; set; }
        public bool Coastal { get; set; }
        public bool Ocean { get; set; }
        public bool Island { get; set; }
        public Civilization.Civs StartingArea { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<BoardSpaceMapPanel> BoardSpaceMapPanels { get; set; }
        public BoardSpace()
        {

        }
    }

    public class MapPanel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int LeftRightSort { get; set; }
        public MapPanel()
        {

        }
    }

    public class Board
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Board()
        {

        }
        public virtual ICollection<BoardMapPanel> BoardMapPanels { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<MapPanel> PanelsInPlay(DatabaseContext context)
        {
            var allBmps = context.BoardMapPanels.ToList();
            var thisBmps = allBmps.Where(it => it.Board == this);
            return thisBmps.Select(it => it.MapPanel);
        }
        public IEnumerable<BoardSpace> BoardSpaces(DatabaseContext context)
        {
            var panels = BoardMapPanels.Select(it => it.MapPanel).ToList();
            var bsmps = context.BoardSpaceMapPanels
                .Select(it => new { BoardSpace = it.BoardSpace, MapPanel = it.MapPanel})
                .ToList().Where(it => panels.Contains(it.MapPanel));
            return bsmps.Select(it => it.BoardSpace).Distinct();
        }
    }

    public class BoardMapPanel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Board Board { get; set; }
        public MapPanel MapPanel { get; set; }

        public BoardMapPanel()
        {

        }

        public BoardMapPanel(Board board, MapPanel panel)
        {
            Board = board;
            MapPanel = panel; 
        }
    }
```

I have known good rows in the database. However, in code, whenever I grab the BoardSpaceMapPanels from the Database and call ToList(), only the MapPanel connection is made in what is produced, where the BoardSpace is null for ALL returned objects. However, I am able to filter these just fine through LINQ .Where calls, so I know that on the Database side, there is a connection between tables. See the method BoardSpaces above, which I had to add the .Select line into the var bsmps to effectively "cast" my DB rows into fully usable BoardSpaceMapPanel objects.

Additionally, I have several other similar many-to-many tables and some return null on rows for BOTH foreign key'd tables and some actually work properly. I have the table BoardMapPanel, which joins the game-session-specific Board with a few MapPanels that are being used. Similarly, I can filter these down by those belonging to a specific board, see PanelsInPlay method in Board class, but on debugging, I am able to see both Board AND MapPanel connections. I'm left thinking that something is fine about how Board and MapPanel classes are built but something wrong with how the BoardSpace class is built, since thats the one that wont bind after calling ToList on the IQueryable.

At work, I use NHibernate because that's what the Database was built on when I got there and following existing conventions is easy.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I could technically just call the .Select like I did to get bsmps in Board.BoardSpaces, but I know this isnt how things should be done and is super frustrating and a verbose refactor.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure where to start, but I see a number of red flags in your code. Firstly that your Board doesn't have navigation properties for the map panels and such and instead is going to the DbContext directly to load them. I'm also wary of entity code that has constructors accepting values that set navigation properties. You need to provide a reproducable example of the read operation you are trying, what data you expect to get returned, vs. what you are actually getting. It seems that you got a bit too deep into trying to code a solution without vetting the data is retrieving along the way.

Comment: I should have edited the post, I had actually figured this out last week, and it was indeed an issue of nav properties. Adding a nav property in place anywhere I had a foreign key in the DB fixed just about all of my issues. I also built some unit tests to more accurately produce the problem and used those to determine it was fixed, but yes, navigation properties are a must.